# Bootstrap 4 - Responsive caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a new page, where I need block of text in the left down corner. The problem is that every time I try to make it, it's not responsive at all and it's running away from 'section' or it's getting over to the 'nav'. Is there any option to make hold it's place?

I tried "position absolute", "margins", "padings", "Bootstrap 4 utilities", but I can't get it work. Do you have any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="container-fluid p-0">
            <section class="pr-5 pl-5" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');">
                <header> 
                    <img class="logo d-block img-fluid mx-auto" width="200px" src="http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/pepsi.png" alt="Logo" />                     
                </header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Toogle" aria-controls="Toogle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars mx-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Toogle">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0 mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Repliky</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Unikáty</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instalace</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="row Text no-gutters ">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 offset-md-2 mr-3">
                        <h2>I need this block of text to be responsive</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero ex inventore vel error quibusdam animi fugiat, doloribus dolores consectetur nulla deleniti sint blanditiis quod debitis quis vitae officiis tempora numquam.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="button white">Watch video</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');">
                nofun   
            </section>
        </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
/*INSERT*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel');
/*ALL*/
html, body {width: 100% !important;}

body {background: grey !important;}



/*Header*/
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 0 .5rem 0 !important;
}

/* NavBar */
nav {
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-family: 'Cinzel', sans-serif;
    padding: .3rem 0 .3rem 0 !important;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #fff !important;
    margin: 0 25% 0 25%;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    font-style: underline;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 650px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


.Text {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Final Solution - Thanks [Lakindu Gunasekara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509585/lakindu-gunasekara)

```
    section{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 900px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.Text {margin-top: 20%;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height:100vh` in the `section tag`. And to avoid the gap between two sections, I have used a `margin-top:-3.2rem` in the `test class`. Try the snippet below.

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 650px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container-fluid p-0">
    <section class="pr-5 pl-5" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');">
      <header>
        <img class="logo d-block img-fluid mx-auto" width="200px" src="http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/pepsi.png" alt="Logo" />
      </header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Toogle" aria-controls="Toogle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars mx-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Toogle">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0 mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Repliky</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Unikáty</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instalace</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="row Text no-gutters ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 offset-md-2 mr-3">
          <h2>I need this block of text to be responsive</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero ex inventore vel error quibusdam animi fugiat, doloribus dolores consectetur nulla deleniti sint blanditiis quod debitis quis vitae officiis tempora numquam.</p>
          <a href="#" class="button white">Watch video</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');">

      <p>nofun</p>

    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. It's working, but I really want it to be 100vh so I can build design on it as image gallery :/ Is there any option how to do it like that?

Comment: Try now? Left text is responsive but check whether the position is okay. Changed the 100vh to both height and min-height

Comment: It's running again into another section :/ Is there any chance to make it better? Like when the resolution is low it would recalculate the margin so It wouldn't be so down...

BTW If you start the HTML inspector on that page ... It's pretty messed up :/

Comment: Try removing the extra css. Updated the snippet

Comment: Thanks! That looks cool! So It was my mistake all the time :P.... Last question ... How do I make it go more down.. I'm asking cuz I don't want mess up anything

Comment: well use margin-top or margin-bottom and give the units in rem.. Example: Margin-top: 4rem; 
Like that ;) where you want to make it go down?

Comment: Well that's the problem, because I wanted it to have it almost on the bottom of the page and when I set margin for example to 20rem (or %, vh) It's again running away... and I don't know how sometimes that margin reduce.

Comment: oh i got it, try increasing the min-height, it will drag to bottom each section

Comment: I used this and it looks like it's working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes did it work? you can adjust the min-height as you wish and it will drag section to bottom. If it worked, please put a tick as well :D